# String anagram in Java

Tags: java, string, anagram

i am trying to create a program for string anagram that follows these conditions:

1. method should allow only letters, white space, commas and dots in an anagram.  If there are any other characters, then the string cannot contain an anagram.
2. The method should ignore all white space, commas and dots when it checks the text.
3. If there are no letters in the text, then the text cannot be an anagram.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringAnagram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter first string: ");
        String first = in.nextLine().toUpperCase();


        System.out.print("Enter second string: ");
        String second = in.nextLine().toUpperCase();

        String result = isAnagram(first, second);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

private static String isAnagram(String first, String second) {
    String answer = "";


    if (first.matches("[A-Z\\.\\,\\s]")) {
        String st = first.replaceAll("\\.\\,\\s", "");
        String nd = second.replaceAll("\\.\\,\\s", "");
        char[] arraySt = st.toCharArray();
        char[] arrayNd = nd.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(arraySt);   
        Arrays.sort(arrayNd);

            if(Arrays.equals(arraySt, arrayNd)) {
                answer = "Anagram.";
            }

            else {
                answer = "No anagram.";
            }
        }

    else  {
        answer = "No anagram.";
    }
    return answer;
}
}
```

However when the program tests these 2 sentences, they are not anagram but they should be anagram. I have no idea where to look for mistake.

1. Eleven plus two is thirteen.
2. Twelve plus one is thirteen.

Comment: As mentioned below your [String.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String) calls have a bug, but I wanted to point out that if you do this before the comparison to check for out of bound characters, that check would become a lot simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start your method as follows, it will fulfil validations mentioned in the `1st` and the `3rd` points of your question:

```
if (first == null || second == null || first.equals("") || second.equals("") || !first.matches("[A-Za-z,. ]+")
        || !second.matches("[A-Za-z,. ]+")) {
    return "No anagram.";
}
```

The next thing you should do is to replace all white space, commas and dots with `""` in order to ignore them:

```
String st = first.replaceAll("[,. ]+", "");
String nd = second.replaceAll("[,. ]+", "");
```

**The complete code is as follows:**

```
private static String isAnagram(String first, String second) {
    if (first == null || second == null || first.equals("") || second.equals("") || !first.matches("[A-Za-z,. ]+")
            || !second.matches("[A-Za-z,. ]+")) {
        return "No anagram.";
    }
    String answer = "";

    String st = first.replaceAll("[,. ]+", "");
    String nd = second.replaceAll("[,. ]+", "");

    if (st.equals("") || nd.equals("")) {
        return "No anagram.";
    }

    char[] arraySt = st.toCharArray();
    char[] arrayNd = nd.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(arraySt);
    Arrays.sort(arrayNd);

    if (Arrays.equals(arraySt, arrayNd)) {
        answer = "Anagram.";
    } else {
        answer = "No anagram.";
    }
    return answer;
}
```

**A test run:**

```
Enter first string: london
Enter second string: britain
No anagram.
```

**Another test run:**

```
Enter first string: ram
Enter second string: mar
Anagram.
```

**Another test run:**

```
Enter first string: .
Enter second string: .
No anagram.
```

**Another test run:**

```
Enter first string: ,
Enter second string: .
No anagram.
```

**Another test run:**

```
Enter first string: ra.m
Enter second string: a.m.r
Anagram.
```

Comment: Hi, however when i input a dot(.) comma(,) or a space, it shows anagram. We must have missed the 3rd condition

Comment: I did accept your answer. Thank you so much, you have saved me for a sleepless night. Have a nice day sir!

Comment: Now, you have done it correctly . Wish you success!

Answer (score 1):

This: `first.matches("[A-Z\\.\\,\\s]")` tests if the `first` value is a **single character** that is either 1 capital letter, or a dot, or a comma, or any whitespace character.

Completely not what you want.

You can add `System.out.println` statements all over the place to print where your code is and the value of relevant variables. Follow the code along like you're the computer. There where what you think should happen does not match with what the sysout statements tell you – there is a bug there (there can be many, especially if you write this much stuff without testing anything first).

Better yet, use a debugger.

NB: Something as trivial as replacing one of your `No anagram.` strings with anything else just so you know which of the two got triggered would already have helped a lot.

NB: `first.replaceAll("\\.\\,\\s", "");` is also broken; you've written way too much code here; test each individual moving piece. It's like a bike that doesn't do anything after you put it together: Take it apart piece by piece, test each piece individually.

Comment: *"tests if the first value is a **single character**"* I'm not so sure about that. `^[A-Z\\.\\,\\s]$` would, but not the one in the code.

Comment: everything leads to the last else, im so frustrated

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca It's precisely as I wrote. matches checks if the _entire string_ matches the stated regexp. The `^` and `$` are implied with `matches`. What you're thinking of, perhaps, is `find` (which is a method on Pattern).

Answer (score 0):

This solution accepts strings from console input.  That portion is omitted since that is working for you.

The idea is to selectively reduce the essence of what you are comparing to the bare minimum.  Comments are provide to explain the logic.  In the examples, all but the third one report as an anagram.

```
        System.out.println(isAnagram("radar", "darar"));
        System.out.println(isAnagram("ra.,. dar", "d.,a  rar"));
        System.out.println(isAnagram("r+a.,. dar", "d.,a + rar"));
        System.out.println(isAnagram("Eleven plus two is thirteen.", "Twelve plus one is thirteen."));
```

```
   // This method accepts mixed case strings.  The conversion to upper case is
   // done within the method.   
    public static String isAnagram(String first, String second) {  

        // get rid of allowed characters and convert to upper case 
        String st = first.replaceAll("[., ]","").toUpperCase();
        String nd = second.replaceAll("[., ]","").toUpperCase();

        // Now get rid of all alpha characters and compare to the empty string.
        // Only if both are equal are the strings potential anagrams.  
        // Otherwise, the illegal characters would be present.
        if (st.replaceAll("[A-Z]","").equals("") &&
                nd.replaceAll("[A-Z]","").equals("")) {

             // this is your original code
             char[] arraySt = st.toCharArray();
             char[] arrayNd = nd.toCharArray();
             Arrays.sort(arraySt);   
             Arrays.sort(arrayNd);

             // don't set a value just return it's an
             // anagram
             if (Arrays.equals(arraySt, arrayNd)) {
                     return "Anagram.";
             } 
        }
        // Otherwise, it's not
        return "No Anagram.";
   }
```